# Android - Second of Two Buttons in Fragment Is Unresponsive

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have a Master/Detail layout, and one of the Detail fragments I use contains two buttons.  In order to distinguish between clicks on the two separate buttons, I have my onClick() function set up inside the detail fragment class as follows:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("Click on:");
        //The switch statement determines which button was pressed
        switch (view.getId()) {
            //If it's the calculation button
            case R.id.button_calc:
                System.out.println("Calculation button!");
                //code...
                break;
            //Otherwise, if it's the save data button
            case R.id.button_saveData:
                System.out.println("Save button!");
                //code...
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }
```

The two buttons are declared in XML as follows:

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_calc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/button_singleCalc"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_saveData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/button_saveData"/>
```

When I tap button_calc, it changes color, produces the clicking sound and performs the code as expected.  When I tap button_saveData, though, it only changes color - no click sound, and no code execution, not even the println() (which works fine in button_calc).

EDIT: Not sure it matters, but I am developing this on a Nexus 10 with Android 4.2.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you call findViewById(R.id.button_saveData).setOnClickListener(this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, I can see nothing amiss with the code you have posted.

For me, I prefer to put the onClick() events directly in the xml, I have a history in web development so I guess it feels more natural to me.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button_calc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button_singleCalc"
    android:onClick="onClickCalculation" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button_saveData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button_saveData"
    android:onClick="onClickSaveData" />
```

Then in the containing activity (not the fragment)

```
public void onClickCalculation(View view) {
        System.out.println("Calculation button!");
        //code...
}

public void onClickSaveData(View view) {
        System.out.println("Calculation button!");
        //code...
}
```